# Can MemoryPool<byte>.Rent(int minBufferSize ) capable of returning a IMemoryOwner<byte> bigger than asked?

Tags: c#, system.memory

I understand that the internal buffer used by `IMemoryOwner<byte>.Memory` can be larger than asked. But, is `IMemoryOwner<byte>.Memory.Length` defined with what I asked or with the size of the internal buffer ? The document seems not accurate enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look.

[`MemoryPool<T>.Rent`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Memory/System/Buffers/MemoryPool.cs,24) is abstract, so we'll go looking for an implementation. [`ArrayMemoryPool<T>.Rent`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Memory/System/Buffers/ArrayMemoryPool.cs,14) looks like a good, representative candidate. That implementation looks like this:

```
public sealed override IMemoryOwner<T> Rent(int minimumBufferSize = -1)
{
    if (minimumBufferSize == -1)
        minimumBufferSize = 1 + (4095 / Unsafe.SizeOf<T>());
    else if (((uint)minimumBufferSize) > MaximumBufferSize)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.minimumBufferSize);

    return new ArrayMemoryPoolBuffer(minimumBufferSize);
}
```

Let's chase that into [`ArrayMemoryPoolBuffer`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Memory/System/Buffers/ArrayMemoryPool.ArrayMemoryPoolBuffer.cs,a3a8383bbf15430c):

```
private sealed class ArrayMemoryPoolBuffer : IMemoryOwner<T>
{
    private T[]? _array;

    public ArrayMemoryPoolBuffer(int size)
    {
        _array = ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Rent(size);
    }

    public Memory<T> Memory
    {
        get
        {
            T[]? array = _array;
            if (array == null)
            {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException_ArrayMemoryPoolBuffer();
            }

            return new Memory<T>(array);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        T[]? array = _array;
        if (array != null)
        {
            _array = null;
            ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Return(array);
        }
    }
}
```

The `new Memory<T>(array)` means that `Memory<T>.Length` will just be the size of the underlying array: we don't have any logic to have a smaller `Memory<T>` wrapping a larger array. So let's see if `ArrayPool<T>.Shared.Rent` gives us back an array of the correct size...

Again this is [abstract](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ArrayPool.cs,a2af42d69058d8ca), but we can find an implementation at [`ConfigurableArrayPool<T>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ArrayPool.cs,a2af42d69058d8ca). The meat of that method is:

```
int index = Utilities.SelectBucketIndex(minimumLength);
if (index < _buckets.Length)
{
    // Search for an array starting at the 'index' bucket. If the bucket is empty, bump up to the
    // next higher bucket and try that one, but only try at most a few buckets.
    const int MaxBucketsToTry = 2;
    int i = index;
    do
    {
        // Attempt to rent from the bucket.  If we get a buffer from it, return it.
        buffer = _buckets[i].Rent();
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            if (log.IsEnabled())
            {
                log.BufferRented(buffer.GetHashCode(), buffer.Length, Id, _buckets[i].Id);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }
    while (++i < _buckets.Length && i != index + MaxBucketsToTry);

    // The pool was exhausted for this buffer size.  Allocate a new buffer with a size corresponding
    // to the appropriate bucket.
    buffer = new T[_buckets[index]._bufferLength];
}
else
{
    // The request was for a size too large for the pool.  Allocate an array of exactly the requested length.
    // When it's returned to the pool, we'll simply throw it away.
    buffer = new T[minimumLength];
}
```

We can see that the pool has multiple buckets, with each bucket containing arrays of a specified size. This method is finding the bucket of arrays which are just larger than the requested size; if that bucket is empty it goes looking at larger buckets. If it fails to find anything, it creates a new array with the *bucket size*; only if the requested size is larger than the pool can manage does it create an array of the exact requested size.

So it's very unlikely that the array underlying the `Memory<T>` has the requested size, and the construction of the `Memory<T>` does nothing to pretend that the `Memory<T>` is smaller than its underlying array.

The conclusion is that `IMemoryOwner<byte>.Memory.Length` can indeed be larger than requested.

Comment: thanks for seeking. I did not know about https://source.dot.net/ which is  awesome.

Comment: The bad thing is I need to store somewhere the actual length of data I put on my Memory<byte>

Comment: You could always `.Slice` it to get a `Memory<T>` of whatever size you want. Then `.Length` will be whatever you set it (provided it's not larger than it was originally)

Comment: yes but I need somewhere to bind the IMemoryOwner and the sliced Memory<byte> for the disposal

Comment: @Perfect28, did you manage to resolve this? I also need to pass the `IMemoryOwner` so that the `Memory` it references can be disposed of (returned to the pool), but I also need the caller to know how much of that memory was used.